# How to get a disk's sector number of the INODE. C, Linux?

Tags: c, linux

Is there a way to "translate" INODE number into the disk sector number by using C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, standard C does not provide any support for this.

The inode number designates an entry with information about the file in a file system. That entry has further information for the device driver, which would determine where it is on the storage device. This information is normally accessed only by device drivers, not standard user programs. Also, a file may have its parts stored in multiple places on disk, not a single sector or contiguous sequence of sectors.

If you are writing a device driver, there are structures and kernel services you would need to know about in order to write the driver. You could learn about these from textbooks or reference materials.

Largely the same knowledge would be required to write a user-level (but privileged) program to read the file system and device data and interpret it to determine where the parts of the file are stored.